# Booting Linux on an 2006 iMac

Tags: imac, startup, unix

I have removed a hard drive from my 2006 iMac and installed Ubuntu on it from another computer. However, after putting it back in the iMac, it is not able to boot. I am getting a question mark instead. Can anyone provide assistance?

Comment: I hope you have the original Mac CD installer - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123512/is-it-possible-to-ditch-os-x-and-install-bsd-on-my-3rd-gen-macbook-pro/123514#123514 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/165175/replacing-os-x-with-windows-linux-on-aging-mac/165191#165191 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410322/macbook-air-with-bootcamp-wanting-removable-linux-devices-without-refind for starters.

Comment: The boot sequence on a PC and a Mac differs - the mac does not know how to read the disk. I think you will have to create a bootable image on a USB flash drive and boot of that and then install. Google gives many guides on how to do this.

Comment: mandesi: I am currently prohibited from posting an an answer to your question on this webpage. However, I did post my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53512/how-do-i-install-linux-on-an-intel-imac-with-no-os-nor-cd-drive/424239#424239).